# How to extract & show data informations of web page

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping

i have a problem & i need some help please
i want to creat a program [C#] to extract a data informations from a website & show the informations on my program
i'm not good with this methode & i need a exemple (to learn it)
so for exemple i have this website:www.whatismyip.com
i want to extract just for exemple the informations of country (Country: USA) from the webpage:

```
<div class="country">Country:</div> <div class="the-country">USA
```

& show it in my program [C#]like this (Country: USA)
i very need a help to resolve this problem please if some one know a methode or any think please

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar, but it was for checking current minecraft version. I used [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). It will allow you to read in the code and sort for whatever information you need. Here's the code I used for it.

```
        Regex Regex = new Regex("[^0-9.]");
        HtmlWeb client = new HtmlWeb();
        //Check Server version
        try
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = client.Load("https://minecraft.net/download");
            HtmlNodeCollection Nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p//a[@href]");

            ServerVersion = Regex.Replace(Nodes[4].InnerText, String.Empty).Remove(0, 1).TrimEnd('.');
            BStripServerVersion.Text = ServerVersion + "  |";
            FileName = (Nodes[6].InnerText);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

You will probably have to fix some areas and search for div classes.
My code reads in all paragraph/ahref statements in the webpage, and then stores it in a array. Afterwards - I had to manually go through till I found the right one I wanted. I believe this will would for you too. My code may/may not be efficient but it gives you a idea.

You can also use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class too.